# Set a screen session name at the command prompt

Tags: gnu-screen

I am trying to create a simple alias that will allow me to create a new screen and set its name simple by typing `newscreen {screenname}` where `{screenname}` is set at the prompt.

For example, I would like to be able to create the following alias:

`alias newscreen='screen -D -R -S {screenname}'`

Then at the command prompt, type:

`$ newscreen client`

This would then start a new screen for me, and give it a name of `client`

That way, I could resume the screen with `screen -r client`.

Can someone point out to me the best way to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but you may also want to check out [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/). It is more user friendly than screen IMO.

Comment: Why not just use `alias newscreen='screen -D -R -S'`?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you alias the first part without the screen name: `alias newscreen='screen -D -R -S'`

And then `$ newscreen client`

And further down the line `screen -r client`

Comment: The clearest answer I ever see

Comment: Googlers: the required switch for setting a name is simply `-S`, [credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202111/how-can-i-assign-a-name-for-a-screen/3309696#3309696)